# Selecting items in a drop down list using jQuery on Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have a rather odd problem with something that works fine on Chrome but doesn't work properly on Firefox.

I am selecting items in a couple of drop down lists using jQuery. This works fine, but if I tab to one of the lists and then use the up/down arrows to scroll through the selection it acts as if it is at the top of the list instead of at the point I selected.

As an example, imagine I have a list with 15 items and I use jQuery to set the list to the value of the fifth item. This works fine and the fifth item shows in the list. However, if I use the tab key to navigate to the list and then press the up arrow, instead of moving to the fourth item it moves to the first item in the list. If, instead of pressing the up arrow, I use the down arrow, it navigates to the second item in the list instead of the sixth.

Once this 'jump' has occurred it works normally and scrolling up and down produces the expected results.

As stated above, this odd and unexpected behaviour does not occur when using Chrome. (I cannot currently test in IE for reasons that I won't go into.)

Does anyone know why this would be occurring? Does some extra value need updating for it to work correctly in Firefox?

Comment: Post some code! Either here or jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly a 'proper' answer, but... The project I am working on currently uses jQuery 1.6.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.16. If I update my references to use the latest versions (1.10.2 & 1.10.4 respectively) it behaves as it should do.